# Index for trivial pursuit game's spaces

Tags: indexing, geometry

I'm trying to code a trivial pursuit game. I want to give an id for every space of the board in order to use them for the movements. I need to know for every space which is next to which/match with each other.

But because of the geometry of the board(extern circle + radii), I didn't find the right logic behind this.

I am thinking of an ID based on 7 numbers (for the 6 radii + the circle). For example :

```
//this is not my code, i'm just trying to show example of IDs

center = [0][0][0][0][0][0][-2]
one on the "2nd radius" = [0][3][0][0][0][0][-2]
one the circle and the "3rd radius" = [0][0][6][0][0][0][22]
one on the circle = [0][0][0][0][0][0][21]
```

I have no idea if it's gonna work or if it's optimal, i will try and see.
If some of you have any better idea for name the ID, i would be happy to listen to them.

**Here is an image of the board.**

[image: Board divided into boxes]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gOPm.jpg)

Thank you for helping!

Comment: So you need... what? Get ID having coordinates?

Comment: No i need ID to associate spaces with each other. For example if I roll a 4 i want to make 4 iterations to increment or decrement the index.

Comment: Do you believe that your problem is more clear now? Short answer is -  if you need an id - give it... But it is worth to show what is done and what difficulties you have met. For now problem is too abstract.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm french and not fluent in english yet so I've tried to give a simple explanation but i understand that with no information it's become too abstract. So i edited my post and tried to explain one solution/idea. I would be glad if you give me a feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, seeems you are inventing some coordinate system for this wheel for easy addressing and easy transtions between cells. System with many indices looks too complex.

Perhaps two-index scheme would be appropriate. Resembles polar coordinates:

The first index `0..6` as distance from the center.
The second one `1..42` - angular position.

So center cell is `A[0][0]`  (the second index is not defined, we can choose any)

It's neighbors are `A[1][1], A[1][8], A[1][15] ..A[1][36]`  (marked with 1 at your picture)

Similar for the next cells at the rays  `A[2][1], A[2][8], A[2][15] ..A[2][36]` and so on

Wheel cells are `A[6][1], A[6][2]..A[6][42]`

Now neighbor cells have coordinates where one index differs by 1 (except for central cell, extra case)

Is this scheme suitable?